AJAX Patch Request returns empty in Laravel Controller
I am trying to update a resource in Laravel sending a PATCH request to my controller.
This is my AJAX call
    $.ajax('profile', { // Replace with your actual endpoint URL
    type: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'), // CSRF token for Laravel
        // 'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'PATCH'
    },
    data:  {status: 'some status'},
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
})
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });

And currently my Controller simply gives back the request data as a response
public function update(ProfileUpdateRequest $request)
{
 return response()->json(['message' => 'Data updated successfully', 'data' => $request->all()]);
}

I get the message 'Data updated sucessfully', the data array however, is completely empty.
I've already tried it with type: 'POST' and spoofing the method in the data array with _method: 'PATCH', which led to the message "'POST' is not a supported method for this route."
Any ideas?
EDIT:
ProfileUpdateRequestClass:
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class ProfileUpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule|array|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
//            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
//            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
        ];
    }
}


What's the purpose of returning $request->all()?

Just seeing if the request is properly sent to the controller and if it's filled with data.

You send only status with request to the controller.

I can use as many arguments as I want, none will be sent back. This was just an example

Are you going to update user data? Because you are using ProfieUpdateRequest.

Yes that was what I was trying to do. But I can't even get to access the data sent, so that was the problem I was trying to focus on. The rules of ProfileUpdateRequest are empty btw.

Please show the ProfileUpdateRequest class

@TUPKAP added to the post

When you set 'Content-Type': 'application/json' you must explicitly send json encoded data:
$.ajax("profile", {

    method: "PATCH",  // method is used instead of type in latest versions of JQuery
    contentType:"application/json", // there is an option to set 'Content-Type' without using headers
    headers: {
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": "{{ csrf_token() }}" // this may be a more concise option for CSRF-TOKEN
    },

    data: '{"status": "some status"}',  // or if you prefer: JSON.stringify ({status: "some status"})

    .....


But then in your ProfileUpdateRequest you have to manually extract the data:
class ProfileUpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    .....

    protected function prepareForValidation()
    {
        $this->merge(json_decode($this->getContent(), associative: true));
    }

    .....

My suggestion is to leave the default contentType in the request (application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8) and proceed more simply:
$.ajax("profile", {

    method: "PATCH",

    headers: {
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    },

    data: {status: "some status"},
    
    .....

In this way return response()->json(['message' => 'Data updated successfully', 'data' => $request->all()]); will provide the expected result
